# Mathematical rigour in Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I understand these statements but they lack rigour.
How do you define these statements rigorously?

1. If there are $a$ varieties of soup and $b$ varieties of salad, then there are $a + b$ possible ways to order a meal of soup or salad.
2. If there are $a$ varieties of soup and $b$ varieties of salad then there are $ab$ possible ways to order a meal of soup and salad.

Your help will be appreciated rather than taking the time to downvote the question.

Comment: Do you want to prove them, or simply re-state in more mathematical language as the answers so far have done?

Comment: These statements are quite rigorous enough. If you try to dress them up in more formalism you will only make life harder for your readers.

Comment: @Niing You get less choice to order a meal then. Less confused.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ the set of soup varieties, and $B$ be the set of salad varieties, where $|A|=a$ and $|B|=b$ (where $A\cap B=\varnothing$). Then $|A\cup B|=a+b$ and $|A\times B|=ab$.

Comment: Nice answer. This one is a bit more weird question. Does |A| U |B| make any sense?

Comment: The cardinality of a set is a number, so $|A| \cup |B|$ is like writing $5 \cup 6$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how these statements aren't rigorous enough. Here are some obtuse ways to make them more so:

1. Let $A$ be the set of varieties of soup ($|A|=a$) and $B$ the set of varieties of salad ($|B|=b$). Then, since $A\cap B=\emptyset$, $|A\cup B|=a+b$.
2. Let $A$ be the set of varieties of soup ($|A|=a$) and $B$ the set of varieties of salad ($|B|=b$). Then, $|A\times B|=ab$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. I was wondering what would happen if A ∩ B wasn't an empty set. Say the number of elements in the set A ∩ B is 2. Then what would |A U B| and |A × B| equal to?

Comment: $|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$, while $|A\times B|=|A|\times |B|$ regardless of $|A\cap B|$. @user571036

Comment: @MikeEarnest But who does want to order the same thing? If A U B= $a_1$ then A × B gives us a pair like this {$a_1$,$a_1$} which may be we don't want.

Comment: @MikeEarnest If we exclude duplicate pair then is it correct to say, $|A\times B|=|A|\times |B|-|A\cap B|$ ?